# CSS3 Pie not working with SASS/Compass

Tags: compass-sass, sass, css3pie, pie-chart

I'm having trouble getting CSS3Pie to work. I've read several posts on SO and Google and still can't to seem to get it work.

I'm using SASS and compass to write my CSS so I'll post both SCSS and CSS outputs below.

SCSS:

```
$pie-behavior: url(PIE.htc);
$pie-base-class: pie-element;

#header{
background:#fff;
width:$full-width;
height:100px;
margin:$margin-center;

ul{
    width:600px;
    height:$nav-height - 2px;
    padding:55px 0 0;
    margin:0 0 0 250px;
    li{
        @include inline-block;  
        font-size:$font-size - 2px;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:20px 10px;
    }

    a{
        color:#282828;
        text-transform:uppercase;

        &:hover{
            color:red;
        }   
    }
}

    #aabw{
        background:url('../images/aabw.jpg') no-repeat;
        height:190px;
        width:110px;
        position:relative;
        z-index: 0;
        float:right;
        margin: 0 270px 0 0;
        @include pie-element(relative);
        @include box-shadow(#BBBBBB 0px -78px 6px);
    }
}
```

Outputted CSS:

```
#header #aabw {
    background: url("../images/aabw.jpg") no-repeat;
    height: 190px;
    width: 110px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 270px 0 0;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #bbbbbb 0px -78px 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #bbbbbb 0px -78px 6px;
    box-shadow: #bbbbbb 0px -78px 6px;
}
```

My PIE.htc is in the room directory (same folder as my index) and I'm trying to run it locally. I've followed the pie.scss file and nothing seems to work, it may be a case of me missing something blatantly obvious so hopefully someone might be able to spot something I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but try putting the PIE call after the box-shadow call.